# How to rank measurements in a survey?

Tags: ranking

I've designed a Likert-scale survey with 4 measurements:

- x (it has 6 items/questions)
- y (it has 9 items/questions)
- z (it has 7 items/questions)
- w (it has 3 items/questions)

How can I rank these measurements?

In other words: how can I understand which measurement is more important to the respondents? In what order?

for example XYWZ or ZWXY ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the items all share the same scoring scale, you may present the mean score of each measurement.
The rankings should come naturally from the means.

Using the mean allows all scales to be measured in the same interval of possible values, making them comparable.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any resource to confirm your idea so I can reference to it in my paper? Does this idea have any scientific name like "Guttman Theory", etc...

Comment: @HRN I'm sorry but I don't really have a reference for using the mean score. Nevertheless, the mean allows all scales to be measured in the same interval of possible values, making them comparable. I'll add this last part to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking in which order it is best to present scales to participants. If that is so, then it is highly recommended that you essentially randomise order of presentation for each individual. This helps to reduce order presentation bias, according to which the specific placement of a block of items in a survey may prime a particular response pattern in the next block of items **(Couper, 2008).** Practically, if you are, for example, using Qualtrics as a data collection platform, go to options and select 'block randomisation'.

**References:**

Couper, M. P. (2008). *Designing effective web surveys.* New York, NY: Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Thank you. No I meant how to rank the measurements, and according to what "Ertxiem - reinstate Monica" said, it seems that I should consider the mean of the measurements as a factor to rank them.

Comment: @HRN yes, I see. I agree with Ertxiem - reinstate Monica about mean scoring each constrcut and then rank-ordering them